# Android Facebook SDK doesn't call back after login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am new to Android development and I am attempting to implement Facebook Login. I am able to login but I am returned to my login activity. My problem is I am trying to launch my main activity after a successful login and it seems that call back is not happening because I am getting null profile and null accessToken. Any solutions or suggestions?

```
public class LoginContainer extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_container);

        // Status Bar color
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb300")); 
        }


        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        FragmentLogin fragmentLogin = new FragmentLogin();
        fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragmentLogin);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    // Facebook Login Inner class
    public static class FragmentLogin extends Fragment {

        private TextView mTextDetails;
        private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
        private AccessToken accessToken;

        private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
        private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
        private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                displayWelcomeMessage(profile);

                if (profile !=null) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class); 
                    startActivity(intent); 
                    getActivity().finish(); 
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            }
        };

        public FragmentLogin() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();



            mTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {

                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

                }
            };


            mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                    displayWelcomeMessage(newProfile);
                }
            };
            mTokenTracker.startTracking();
            mProfileTracker.startTracking();

            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            if (profile !=null) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class); 
                startActivity(intent); 
                getActivity().finish(); 
            }   

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login_container, container, false);

        }

        private void displayWelcomeMessage(Profile profile) {
            if (profile != null) {
                mTextDetails.setText("Welcome " + profile.getName());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
            //loginButton.setFragment(this);
            loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);

            mTextDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile !=null) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class); 
                startActivity(intent); 
                getActivity().finish(); 
            }   


            //  Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class); 
            //  startActivity(intent); 
            //  getActivity().finish(); 

            AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            if(token != null) { 
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent); 
                getActivity().finish(); 
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
            mProfileTracker.startTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile !=null) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class); 
                startActivity(intent); 
                getActivity().finish(); 
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to login successfully on facebook?

Comment: Yes i am. As soon as I am taken directly back to the login screen.